# R data frame with doubly subscripted variables x[,1]

Tags: r, read.table

How can I create a `data.frame` with some variables `x`,`y` and a doubly subscripted variables `z[,1],z[,2]`?
Here is my code :

```
n = 10
x = rnorm(n,0)
y = rnorm(n,0)
z1 = rnorm(n,0)
z2 = rnorm(n,0)
z=matrix(z1,z2,nrow=length(z1),ncol=2)
data=data.frame(x,y,z)
```

But the results are data with four colomns : `x,y,x1,x2`

What I want to have is something like the table B.3, page 325 in this [paper](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~gwoodwor/BBIText/AppendixBWinbugs.pdf).

Comment: For completeness, can you add the table to your question? There's no guarantee that the PDF is going to be accessible longer term.

Answer (score 0):

That does not work with data.tables, they are always flat `N x M`.

You need a list for this and by assigning `names` to it, it behaves like you want:

```
n = 10
x = rnorm(n,0)
y = rnorm(n,0)
z1 = rnorm(n,0)
z2 = rnorm(n,0)
z=matrix(z1,z2,nrow=length(z1),ncol=2)
# my changes below
l <- list(x,y,z)
names(l) <- c("x","y","z")
l$z[,1]
```